# Restart Service on failure using Ansible

Tags: ansible

Hope someone can help and point me in the right direction as I am new to Ansible. I have an Ansible playbook that installs windows updates and another playbook that checks to see if the specific service is running after the server has been rebooted.

Is there a way in which after reboot if the service is not started then it will attempt to restart the service.

These are my playbooks at the minute

**Windows Update**

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Install all security, critical, and rollup updates
      become: True
      win_updates:
        category_names:
        - SecurityUpdates
        - CriticalUpdates
        server_selection: windows_update
        reboot: no
```

**Service Check**

```yaml
---
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: Active Directory Checks
        block:
          - name: Check Active Directory Domain Services are running
            become: True
            win_service:
              name: "{{ item }}"
              start_mode: auto
              state: started  
            loop:
              - NTDS
              - ADWS
              - Dfs
              - DFSR
              - DNS
              - Kdc
```

Comment: You should probably use Windows Services rather than Ansible playbook for that. You can set up your service to restart in case of failure. Check Windows `sc failure` subcommand.

Comment: @blami: he his using windows service, through the ansible module `win_service` which setup each service as being auto started and up at time the task runs.

Comment: You should get familliar with the concept of idempotence which is central in ansible. Your above task named "Check Active Directory Domain Services are running" is doing exactly what you want. Trying to translate into English: "make sure that <each service in the loop> exists, is in auto start mode and is currently started". Ansible will report OK if the state is aligned, CHANGED if it had to do something to align or ERROR if something went wrong.

Comment: Note that following @blami comment, you can apparently (note: I'm not a windows expert...) set [`failure_actions`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html#parameter-failure_actions) in the module to describe how it should try to restart in case there is a problem

Comment: Thank you all this has helped point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

There is a [failure_actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html#parameter-failure_actions) parameter for this exact requirement. It allows you to set one or more `failure_actions` with or without a timeout between each. You can define a `reboot` of the host, a `restart` of the service or a `run_command` to perform some action. You provide these as a list.

In this example in the [win_service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html#examples) documentation, if the service does not start on the first time it will:

1. try a restart of the service
2. Create the C:\temp directory using `run_command`
3. try another restart after 1s
4. try another restart after 5s
5. reboot the host

```yaml
- name: Set failure actions for a service with no reset period
  ansible.windows.win_service:
    name: service name
    failure_actions:
    - type: restart
    - type: run_command
      delay_ms: 1000
    - type: restart
      delay_ms: 5000
    - type: reboot
    failure_command: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\temp
    failure_reboot_msg: Restarting host because service name has failed
    failure_reset_period_sec: '0xFFFFFFFF'
```

Since you are defining a list of services I suspect you just want a single restart for all of these in the event they don't start.

```yaml
---
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: Active Directory Checks
        block:
          - name: Check Active Directory Domain Services are running
            become: True
            ansible.windows.win_service:
              name: "{{ item }}"
              start_mode: auto
              state: started  
              failure_actions:
                - type: restart
            loop:
              - NTDS
              - ADWS
              - Dfs
              - DFSR
              - DNS
              - Kdc
```